# Normalizing issue with data history

Tags: entity-relationship, database-normalization

I have two entities: `Location` and `Employee`. Each employee works in a single location at a time. For any given moment in time, the model is as follows:

[image]

There is, however, a requirement to also store historical information for all locations and employees for every end-of-month. I can achieve this by adding a `Month` PK attribute in both entities, but: **how do I handle the relationship in that case?**

A foreign key has to reference a composite PK in its entirety. Several alternatives come to mind:

*Option 1:* repeat the `Month` attribute in the `Employee` entity to get the full PK as FK attributes. This feels a bit redundant? If an employee has existed in a given month, surely she has to work in a location in the same month - i.e. the two `Month` attributes have to always have the exact same value:

[image]

*Option 2:* re-use the `Month` attribute in the PK of the `Employee` entity as a foreign key referencing `Location`. I don't even know if this is allowed (note: I'm going to be using SQL Server eventually, if it matters here)?

[image]

*Option 3:* create a separate bridge entity that holds the history of Location-Employee relationships. This feels kind of neat, but then again I have some doubts as to whether or not I can use one `Month` attribute here or if I need two of them. Also, it would allow many-to-many relationships (an employee in several locations on a given month), which is not supposed to happen in this case and I'd like to be able to enforce this in the data model.

[image]

Am I missing something obvious here? What is the "correct" and properly normalized solution? Or should I just leave the FK constraints out?

Comment: A FK says values somewhere appear as a key somewhere else. Where that's so (and it isn't a consequence of other declarations), declare it; otherwise, don't. FKs fall out of a design (including normalization), they don't drive it. There are also many similar constraints that (like all constraints) should be enforced, although SQL doesn't support that declaratively. Find the most clear/straightforward design. Also, read about when SQL FKs contain nulls. PS This is a faq, re basics of simple historical/temporal designs.